# Why doesn't the vector and text align itself vertically in this navbar?

Tags: css, html

I am working on a navbar in HTML. I don't understand why the elements do not line up nicely within the navbar.

```css
body {
    background-color: #ECEFF1; /* Blue Gray 50 */
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

#header {
    background-color: #ba68c8; /* Purple 300 */
    color: #ffffff; /* White */
    height: 24px;
    padding: 8px;
}

.header-link {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">

    <a class="header-logo" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.sigmacubes.com/img/logo_h.svg" height="24" />
    </a>

    <a class="header-link" href="#">
      Text
    </a>

</div>
```

Although the svg is aligned vertically, the text does not stay aligned vertically. Why is this happening?

Comment: What are you expecting this to look like? I see nothing unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Is `vertical-align:middle;` an option for your header-link class? 
Maybe add `display: table-cell;` in conjunction with `vertical-align:middle;` if that further matches the look that you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is reduce the header-link font size to 20px and give it position absolute

```
.header-link {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Or if you want to keep the size 24px you better give it margin-top: -5px too

```
.header-link {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```